# Javascript: how to include a string literal into another one?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax

Say we've got a tag as follows:

```
<div ng-init="html='<a ng-click=\'openPopover(\'#ChoixDeLaDensiteRecherche\')\'>click</a>'"></div>
```

(I actually need to set variables with HTML code)

This doesn't work. How to write escaping for the innermost simple quotes?

PS: I don't know why \" \" didn't worked either.

[EDIT 1] The lecture error: 
[Error] Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 12-12 [] in expression [openPopover(].

Comment: There is no javascript anywhere in this question. The `ng-init` attribute is an [Angular expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), which is similar to (but not) javascript.

Comment: If it's being interpreted by _HTML_ parsers before the _JavaScript_ parsers, you'll need to HTML encode special characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **`&quot;`**, [example](http://jsfiddle.net/5fcwbnph/):

```
<div onclick="alert('<a ng-click=&quot;openPopover(\'#ChoixDeLaDensiteRecherche\')&quot;>click</a>')">AAAAA</div>
```

Comment: This solves the lexer error. But for some reasons (still investigating) does not enable the openPopover() to trigger. Any idea? @Volune

Comment: Forget about it, it's a ng-scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you're not closing the literal within the parentheses? It seems like you've escaped the closing quote outside the parentheses.

Try this:

`<div onclick="alert('<a ng-click=&quot;openPopover(\'#ChoixDeLaDensiteRecherche\')&quot;>click</a>')">click</div>`